# How can i set loading screen when apps check login status?

Tags: flutter, dart

I use SharedPreferences to keep login status. its works fine.

but after close my app when I open this. it's showing all my screen like flash screen then its stay on its right screen.

but I don't want this and this not good.

I want when apps check login status its shows a loading screen or anything then after completing its show apps right screen.

how can I do this?

Here is my login status check code

```
 checkLoginStatus() async {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

if (sharedPreferences.getString("empid") == null) {
  Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Home()),
      (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
   }
}
```

Comment: have you created singleton class for store user pref details? thats easy way, code seem right, just reset details before `pushAndRemoveUntil `

Comment: yes i already have this..
brother i just seeking when check login status i need show loading screen.

when apps found right status then loading stop and stay.

Comment: are you following bloc pattern ?

Comment: ScopedModel brother

Comment: and you want something like that, first time its show login screen, after whenever come back then its show home screen?

Comment: yes but here is a problem

when apps run again first time its goto my homescreen
 
then back my login screen. because apps have no user logged already.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201876/discussion-between-masum-billah-sanjid-and-dharmesh-mansata).

Answer (score 0):

Personnally I like to use a variable **_isLoading** which I set to **true** at the beginning of my login method using a **setState**. Then using this bool you just have to change what is displayed in your Scaffold.

```
bool _isLoading = false;

checkLoginStatus() async {
    setState() => _isLoading = true;
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    if (sharedPreferences.getString("empid") == null) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Home()),
           (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
    } else {
        setState() => _isLoading = false;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: In your case this might be more relevant:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    switch (currentUser.status) {
      case AuthStatus.notSignedIn:
        return LoginPage();
      case AuthStatus.signedIn:
        return HomePage();
      default:
        return LoadingPage();
    }
  }
```

My **currentUser** is just a class that I've created containing an enum **AuthStatus** which can have the value **notSignedIn** or **signedIn**. If you set the status to null while loading you can display your loading screen.

Comment: i know this my brother .
when apps is open its first choice is log in screen. but if user logged already.
apps not show first time home screen first its show log in screen then when checklogin status detect they have a logged user then its pass home screen automatically.


but i want just if user logged already i just show first time my home screen or a loading.


but firstly its show my login screen if user logged already that is the problem.

and this is not look good .

Comment: In that case you can use a page that will build either the login page if the user is not connected, the home screen when the user is logged and a loading screen while loading and neither of the other case is valid.

Answer (score 0):

**Snippet**

```
void main async {

bool isUserLogin = await User.isUserLogin();
  if (isUserLogin) { // wait untill user details load
    await User.currentUser.loadPastUserDetails();
  }

  runApp(MyApp(isUserLogin));

}
```

and

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  bool isUserLogin;
  MyApp(this.isUserLogin);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var defaultRoot = isUserLogin ? HomePage() : LoginScreen();

    final material =  MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: defaultRoot,
    );

    return material;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!